# Python BeautifulSoup - Scraping Div Spans and p tags - also how to get exact match on div name

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have two divs I am trying to scrape, with the same name (but there are other divs on the page also with a partial name match, that I dont want). 
The first I just need the text inside each span element. In the second I need the text inside the span element, for the first
row then I need the text inside the

tags for row 2 and 3.

I'm not even too sure why I need to slice at the end of the divs (I think because the div class col returns more than the 2 relevant divs, but adding :1 at the end of divs seems to help)

My questions are - how to get an exact match on the div name
How to scrape inside the p tags
How to combine the results from the above. I can get the text inside the span tags, as shown below but as I say above I need the text inside the p tags also and combine the results.

The data is coming from the player details section in this URL - https://www.skysports.com/football/player/141016/alisson-ramses-becker

The html looks like this

```
    <div class="row-table details -bp30">
        <div class="col">
            <p>Name: <strong><span itemprop="name">Alisson Ramses Becker</span></strong></p>                <p>Date of birth:<span itemprop="birthDate">02/10/1992</span></p>                <p>Place of birth:<span itemprop="nationality"> Brazil</span></p>               
                        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <p>Club: <span itemprop="affiliation">Liverpool</span></p><p>Squad: 13</p>                <p>Position: Goal Keeper</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Relevant piece of my program

```
        premier_soup1 = player_soup.find('div', {'class': 'row-table details -bp30'})
        premier_soup_tr = premier_soup1.find_all('div', {'class': 'col'})

        divs = player_soup.find_all( 'div', {'class': 'col'})
        for div in divs[:1]:
            para = div.find_all('p')
            print(para)
```

Output -

```
    [<p class="text-h4 title">Player Details</p>, <p>Name: <strong><span itemprop="name">Alisson Ramses Becker</span></strong></p>, <p>Date of birth:<span itemprop="birthDate">02/10/1992</span></p>, <p>Place of birth:<span itemprop="nationality"> Brazil</span></p>, <p>Club: <span itemprop="affiliation">Liverpool</span></p>, <p>Squad: 13</p>, <p>Position: Goal Keeper</p>]
```

Also - I know I can get the span text with this

```
divs = player_soup.find_all( 'div', {'class': 'col'})
for div in divs[:1]:
    spans = div.find_all('span')
    for span in spans:       
        print(span.text, ",", end=' ')
```

Output -

```
Alisson Ramses Becker , 02/10/1992 ,  Brazil , Liverpool ,
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main question is how to extract the text from `<p>` , which does not contain `<span>`.

[*NavigableString*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) *A string corresponds to a bit of text within a tag*. So you can extract text  if they are instances of `NavigableString`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString
html = "your example"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
for e in soup.find("p"):
    print(e,type(e))
#Name:  <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
#<strong><span itemprop="name">Alisson Ramses Becker</span></strong> <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

Real code:

```
resultset = soup.find_all("p")
maintext = []
for result in resultset:
    for element in result:
        if isinstance(element, NavigableString):
            maintext.append(element)

print(maintext)
# ['Name: ', 'Date of birth:', 'Place of birth:', 'Club: ', 'Squad: 13', 'Position: Goal Keeper']
```

Equal to

```
[element for result in resultset for element in result if isinstance(element, NavigableString)]
```

My full test code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString
html = """

    <div class="row-table details -bp30">
        <div class="col">
            <p>Name: <strong><span itemprop="name">Alisson Ramses Becker</span></strong></p>                <p>Date of birth:<span itemprop="birthDate">02/10/1992</span></p>                <p>Place of birth:<span itemprop="nationality"> Brazil</span></p>               
                        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <p>Club: <span itemprop="affiliation">Liverpool</span></p><p>Squad: 13</p>                <p>Position: Goal Keeper</p>
        </div>
    </div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
resultset = soup.find_all("p")
fr = [element for result in resultset for element in result if isinstance(element, NavigableString)]
spanset = [e.text for e in soup.find_all("span",{"itemprop":True})]
setA = ["".join(z) for z in zip(fr,spanset)]
final = setA + fr[len(spanset):]
print(final)
```

Output

```
['Name: Alisson Ramses Becker', 'Date of birth:02/10/1992', 'Place of birth: Brazil', 'Club: Liverpool', 'Squad: 13', 'Position: Goal Keeper']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have rights to scrap this site and there are no APIs or json returns, one slow way to do it is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
 <div class="row-table details -bp30">
        <div class="col">
            <p>Name: <strong><span itemprop="name">Alisson Ramses Becker</span></strong></p>                <p>Date of birth:<span itemprop="birthDate">02/10/1992</span></p>                <p>Place of birth:<span itemprop="nationality"> Brazil</span></p>               
                        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <p>Club: <span itemprop="affiliation">Liverpool</span></p><p>Squad: 13</p>                <p>Position: Goal Keeper</p>
        </div>
    </div>
'''

soup = bs(html,'html5lib')

data = [d.find_all('p') for d in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'col'})]

value = []
for i in data:
    for j in i:
        value.append(j.text)

print(value)
```