# How to get text from <div> with included <span> with beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This is the Html code

```
<div class="mxjs-variant-selector mx-variant-selector"
     data-ga-label=""
     name="" >Title <br>
              <span class="mx-price">Price</span>
</div>
```

I want to get the `Title` and the `Price` in various variables

This is my Code

```
name_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'mxjs-variant-selector mx-variant-selector'})
title = name_box.text.strip()
name_box1 = soup.find("div", class_="mxjs-variant-selector mx-variant-selector").find("span", class_="mx-price").text
price = name_box1
```

on title i get

```
Title
(with newline)
Price
```

on price i get

```
Price
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have edit fist post

Comment: Can you add the url of the webpage that you are trying to scrap?  or additila HTML data which includes the price which you are trying to print

Comment: what [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084902/python-beautifulsoup-scraping-div-spans-and-p-tags-also-how-to-get-exact-mat/) on this question , it may contain what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the text from the `span` element, then remove it from the soup. You can then get the `title`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="mxjs-variant-selector mx-variant-selector"
     data-ga-label=""
     name="" >Title <br>
              <span class="mx-price">Price</span>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

div = soup.find("div", class_="mxjs-variant-selector mx-variant-selector")
price = div.span.text
div.span.extract()
title = div.get_text(strip=True)

print(title)
print(price)
```

Giving you:

```
Title
Price
```

Comment: thanks that works for me. i just need to replace `title = soup.div.get_text(strip=True)` with `title = div.get_text(strip=True)`

Comment: Indeed, that is what it was meant to be.