# How to collect specific data from HTML using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a weather forecast by scraping web-pages. (My prevoius [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992) )

My code:

```
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from keyboard import press_and_release



def weather_forecast2():
    print('Hello, I can search up the weather for you.')
    while True:
        inp = input('Where shall I search? Enter a place :').capitalize()
        print('Alright, checking the weather in ' + inp + '...')

        URL = 'https://www.yr.no/nb'

        "Search for a place"
        driver = webdriver.Edge()  # Open Microsoft Edge
        driver.get(URL)  # Goes to the HTML-page of the given URL
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("søk")  # Find the search input box
        element.send_keys(inp)  # Enter input
        press_and_release('enter')  # Click enter

        cURL = driver.current_url  # Current URL

        "Find data"
        driver.get(cURL)  # Goes to the HTML-page that appeared after clicking button
        r = requests.get(cURL)  # Get request for contents of the page
        print(r.content)  # Outputs HTML code for the page
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')  # Parse the data with BeautifulSoup(HTML-string, HTML-parser)
```

I want to collect the temperatures from the page. I know that the xpaths to the elements Im looking for are

> //*[@id="dailyWeatherListItem0"]/div[2]/div[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/span[2]/span[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/text()
> //*[@id="dailyWeatherListItem0"]/div[2]/div[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/span[2]/span[3]/text()
> //*[@id="dailyWeatherListItem1"]/div[2]/div[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/span[2]/span[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/text()
> //*[@id="dailyWeatherListItem1"]/div[2]/div[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/span[2]/span[3]/text()
> //*[@id="dailyWeatherListItem2"]/div[2]/div[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/span[2]/span[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/text()
> //*[@id="dailyWeatherListItem2"]/div[2]/div[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/span[2]/span[3]/text()
> //*[@id="dailyWeatherListItem3"]/div[2]/div[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/span[2]/span[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/text()
> //*[@id="dailyWeatherListItem3"]/div[2]/div[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/span[2]/span[3]/text()
>
> //etc...

Basically I want to collect the following two elements nine times:

> //*[@id="dailyWeatherListItem{NUMBERS0-8}"]/div[2]/div[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/span[2]/span[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/text()
> //*[@id="dailyWeatherListItem{NUMBER0-8}"]/div[2]/div[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911992/scrape-divspan-from-html-page?noredirect=1#comment120036355_67911992)/span[2]/span[3]/text()

How can I use *driver.find_element_by_xpath* to do this? Or is there a more efficient function?

Comment: Can you include the definition for `press_and_release` please as well as all the necessary import statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can correctly retrieve the url then you can use that as the referer header, as well as the location id within that url, to call the API which actually returns the forecasts. I don't have your definition for `press_and_release` so code is tested without that.

```
import requests, re
from selenium import webdriver

# url = 'https://www.yr.no/nb/v%C3%A6rvarsel/daglig-tabell/2-6058560/Canada/Ontario/London'

def get_forecast(str:url)->object:
    
    location_id = re.search(r'daglig-tabell/(.*?)/', url).group(1)
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'referer': url}
    forecasts = requests.get(f'https://www.yr.no/api/v0/locations/{location_id}/forecast', headers=headers).json()
    return forecasts 


def get_forecast_url():
    
    print('Hello, I can search up the weather for you.')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Open Microsoft Edge. (I changed to Chrome)

    while True:

        inp = input('Where shall I search? Enter a place :').capitalize()
        print('Alright, checking the weather in ' + inp + '...')

        URL = 'https://www.yr.no/nb'

        "Search for a place"

        driver.get(URL)  # Goes to the HTML-page of the given URL
        driver.find_element_by_id("page-header__search-button").click() #open search 
        # Find the search input box
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("page-header__search-input")
        element.send_keys(inp)  # Enter input
        press_and_release('enter')  # Click enter

        cURL = driver.current_url  # Current URL
        print(get_forecast(cURL))

    driver.quit()
```

Comment: I have modified my code now, but I needed to install ChromeDriverManager to be able to open Chrome, so I added:

Comment: Ok. You could have switched back to Edge by changing that line with the comment,

Comment: Im sorry, I see that my comment got cut short. I got a WebDriverException:  Message: 'MicrosoftWebDriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please download from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=619687, so I switched to Chrome to see if it would work. I got the same exception, so I installed ChromeDriverManager. But now, when I wrote the line driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager.install())  to Open Google Chrome, I got a TypeError: install() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: I tried looking at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self , but I couldn't figure out how to fix my problem

Comment: your chromdriver etc need to be on the environmental path i.e. the containing folder needs to be on the enviromental path or in a folder you point it to with the executable_path arg

Comment: I put the path to chromedriver by going to Control Panel>System>Advanced systemsettings>Environment>Path>Edit>New, then inserting the path to chromedriver, but I still get the same error message.

Comment: path to the folder containing the exe not the exe itself